# How do I do global average pooling in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

How do I do global average pooling in TensorFlow? If I have a tensor of shape `batch_size, height, width, channels = 32, 11, 40, 100`, is it enough to just use `tf.layers.average_pooling2d(x, [11, 40], [11, 40])` as long as channels = classes?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could also do **tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=[1,2])**, specially if your height and width are not defined.

Typically, in a CNN, tensors have a shape of `b, h, w, c` where `b` is the batch size, `w` and `h` correspond to the width and height dimensions, and `c` is the number of channels/filters.

When you reduce along the axis `[1,2]`, you reduce on the first and second dimensions of the tensor (keeping the batch size, and the number of channels/filters)

Comment: I think this is the more general solution for _global_ pooling

Comment: Hey, would mind explaining the [1,2] argument? am having a hard time understanding this, I've read that docs on that function, but is still not making much sense.  Thanks!

Comment: I edited the answer to describe better the [1,2] argument

Comment: Note that this won't work (right now) when deploying to mobile (tflite) - the axis argument (which is the same as the reduction_indices one) is not supported. Check https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/g3doc/tf_ops_compatibility.md for current status (in case it changes after this comment was written).

Comment: This solution is used in many official TF repos, such as https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/2d9d79433b1eeac3f859e44e3c2650270621f43a/research/resnet/resnet_model.py#L302

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass a stride. With padding='valid' (the default), if the spatial extent of the pooling filter is the same as the spatial extent of the image, you will get a 1x1 image out. Other than that, that is how you do it, yes.

Comment: Is that `padding='SAME'` would make no sense when doing global average pooling (but the book i'm reading did this)?