# Migrating from Keras to Tensorflow : "GlobalAveragePooling2D()" and "std bad:alloc"

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Am pretty new to tensorflow and trying to migrate this keras cnn to tensorflow.

```
 inputs = Input(shape=(1, BANDS, 500))

        x = Conv2D(100, kernel_size=(BANDS, 50), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(inputs)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(x)
        x = LeakyReLU()(x)
        x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

        x = Conv2D(100, kernel_size=(1, 1), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(x)
        x = LeakyReLU()(x)
        x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

        x = Conv2D(15, kernel_size=(1, 1), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(x)
        x = Lambda(softmax, arguments={'axis': 1}, name='softmax')(x)

        x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

        model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is the Tf code

```
def sai_net( ):

    network = input_data(shape=[None, NUM_OF_BANDS, 500, 1 ], name='features')
    network = conv_2d(network, 100 , [NUM_OF_BANDS,50 ], activation='relu')
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = dropout(network, 0.25)
    network = conv_2d(network, 100 , [1,1], activation='relu')
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = dropout(network, 0.25)
    network = conv_2d(network, 15, [1,1], activation='relu')
    network = fully_connected(network, 15, activation='softmax')
    network = regression(network, optimizer='momentum', loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                         learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE, name='labels')

    model = tflearn.DNN(network, checkpoint_path=MODEL_PATH + MODEL_NAME, 
                        tensorboard_dir=TRAIN_PATH, tensorboard_verbose=3, max_checkpoints=1)
    return model
```

First of all i am having trouble with how to use GlobalAveragePooling in tf and when i try to use a fully connected layer, it gives a bad:alloc possibly due to excessive memory.

Basically input is a matrix of Bands*500 where bands == 200 in the following case and output is one of 15 scene labels.
Three Questions :

1) How to apply GlobalAveragePooling layer in this network

2) Is std:bad alloc due to the fully connected layer ( 8 gigs of Ram, 256 gigs of ssd )

3) How to apply normalization before activation in this network

Comment: Pooling is a downsampling operation. I don't know what are you trying to do by applying it to softmax as it makes no sense.

Comment: @Nain basically trying to achieve this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fz17fBP8Z7UuWtbtB1zccJv5N3RmX-Od/view?usp=sharing  ( only the ambience model ) via the last step using pooling

Comment: 1) You can use a normal average_pooling layer, and set the window's width and height as the image's width and height. (related stack overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054451/how-do-i-do-global-average-pooling-in-tensorflow)

2) I think you're getting std:bad alloc due to a memory issue, so it may be due to that layer.

3) You can set the activation as None, or define your own activation function.

Comment: thanks but i figured it out quite some time back, posted the answer too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered this ques : so i figured out myself. the bad:alloc was indeed due to the large memory overhead. and the correct network implementation in tf for this [model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fz17fBP8Z7UuWtbtB1zccJv5N3RmX-Od/view) using tflearn library is as follows :

```
def sai_net( ):

    network = input_data(shape=[None, NUM_OF_BANDS, 500, 1 ], name='features')
    print(network.shape) 
    network = conv_2d(network, 100 , [NUM_OF_BANDS,50 ] , strides = [NUM_OF_BANDS,1] )
    print(network.shape) 
    network = tflearn.layers.batch_normalization(network)
    print(network.shape ) 
    network = tflearn.activations.relu(network)
    print(network.shape ) 
    network = dropout(network, 0.25)
    print(network.shape ) 
    network = conv_2d(network, 100 , [1,1])
    print(network.shape ) 
    network = tflearn.layers.batch_normalization(network)
    network = tflearn.activations.relu(network)
    network = dropout(network, 0.25)
    network = conv_2d(network, 15, [1,1], activation='softmax')
    print(network.shape ) 
    network = tflearn.layers.conv.global_avg_pool (network, name='GlobalAvgPool')
    print(network.shape)
    network = regression(network, optimizer='momentum', loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                         learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE, name='labels')

    model = tflearn.DNN( network,tensorboard_dir=TRAIN_PATH, tensorboard_verbose=3 )
    return model
```